# How to start Vim with a clean jumplist

Tags: vim, vimrc, jumplist

I want Vim to start up with a clean jumplist. I don't want to go back to old files i edited in another session when I press CTRL-O. The jumplist is stored in `.viminfo` and I can't get it to disappear from there.

I have tried adding `clearjumps` to my `.vimrc`, but that doesn't work.

In `:h viminfo-'` it says

> '       Maximum number of previously edited files for which the marks
> are remembered.  This parameter must always be included when
> 'viminfo' is non-empty.
> Including this item also means that the jumplist and the
> changelist are stored in the viminfo file.

So I tried to `set viminfo=<50,s10,h` but then vim says

> Must specify a ' value: viminfo=<50,s10,h

I have tried `set viminfo='0,<50,s10,h` but it still doesn't start with a clean jumplist.

The only way I have found that works is `set viminfo=`. But that disables viminfo which I actually would like to keep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This in my vimrc works for me:

```
autocmd VimEnter * :clearjumps
```

Comment: Thank you. This works for me.